# Reduce array of objects with deeply literals keys in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, object, reduce

I'm confused about array transform with reduce method. I can't figure out how to deal with nested object with literal keys.

To brings some advantage, I'll post some example I'm wrote and it work fine:

```
// consider flat array of objects
const names = [
{ name: "Jaden", sname: "Smith", age: 33 }, 
{ name: "Will", sname: "Smith", age: 12 },
{ name: "Jada", sname: "Smith", age: 29 }, 
{ name: "Jose", sname: "Varho", age: 21 },
{ name: "Josephina", sname: "Varho", age: 44 }, 
{ name: "Keanu ", sname: "Reeves", age: 44 }] ;

// suppose i need to transform that array to this shape:
/* {
    "Smith": {
        "Jaden": 33,
        "Will": 12,
        "Jada": 29
    },
    "Varho": {
        "Jose": 21,
        "Josephina": 44
    },
    "Reeves": {
        "Keanu ": 44
    }
}

*/

// this reducer do it's fine:
const shapeIt = (acc, item) => {
    console.log('acc:', JSON.stringify(acc));
    acc[item.sname] = { ...acc[item.sname], [item.name]: item.age }
    return acc
}

const transformShape= (arr) => {
    return arr.reduce((acc, item) => shapeIt(acc, item), {});
}

transformShape(names); //gives required shape
```

So now, let's imaging i have more complex array like:

```
 const flatArray = [
{ "blockId": "first-block", "sectionId": "first-section", "fieldId": "_1", "value": "0" }, 
{ "blockId": "first-block", "sectionId": "first-section", "fieldId": "_2", "value": "1" }, 
{ "blockId": "first-block", "sectionId": "second-section", "fieldId": "_1", "value": "1" }, 
{ "blockId": "second-block", "sectionId": "first-section", "fieldId": "_1", "value": "1" }, 
{ "blockId": "second-block", "sectionId": "some-section", "fieldId": "_2", "value": "3" },
{ "blockId": "third-block", "sectionId": "other-section", "fieldId": "_1", "value": "3" }];

// and i strictly need to get this shape of object:

/* {
    "first-block": {
        "first-section": {
            "_1": "0",
            "_2": "1"
        },
        "second-section": {
            "_1": "1"
        }
    },
    "second-block": {
        "first-section": {
            "_1": "1"
        },
        "some-section": {
            "_2": "3"
        }
    },
    "third-block": {
        "other-section": {
            "_1": "3"
        }
    }
}
*/
```

At this moment I'm write this kind of reduce function. It works but it gives me only last `fieldId` keys of each section in block. if section in one block have more than one `fieldId` - it lose it. I'm watch for a accumulator, and see that only keys with different blockId, sectionId is accumulated, but not different `fieldId`'s.

```
const shapeComplex = (acc, item) => {
    console.log('acc:', JSON.stringify(acc));
    acc[item.blockId] = { ...acc[item.blockId], [item.sectionId]: { [item.fieldId]: item.value } }

    return acc
}

const transformComplex = (arr) => {
    console.log('initialArr: ', arr)
    return arr.reduce((acc, item) => shapeComplex(acc, item), {});
}

transformComplex(flatArray); 
// it gives me shape with only last idField in same section and block:

/*
{
    "first-block": {
        "first-section": {
            "_1": "0"
        },
        "second-section": {
            "_1": "1"
        }
    },
    "second-block": {
        "first-section": {
            "_1": "1"
        },
        "some-section": {
            "_2": "3"
        }
    },
    "third-block": {
        "other-section": {
            "_1": "3"
        }
    }
}
*/
```

Any help, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to copy the properties (fields) of the innermost (section) object:

```
const shapeComplex = (acc, item) => {
    console.log('acc:', JSON.stringify(acc));
    acc[item.blockId] = {
        ...acc[item.blockId],
        [item.sectionId]: {
            ...acc[item.blockId]?.[item.sectionId],
//          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            [item.fieldId]: item.value
        }
    };
    return acc
}
```

I would however recommend to either always use object spread on every level

```
const shapeComplex = (acc, item) => {
    return {
        ...acc,
        [item.blockId]: {
            ...acc[item.blockId],
            [item.sectionId]: {
                ...acc[item.blockId]?.[item.sectionId],
                [item.fieldId]: item.value
            }
        }
    };
}
```

or to use mutations:

```
const shapeComplex = (acc, {blockId, sectionId, fieldId, value}) => {
    const block = acc[blockId] ?? (acc[blockId] = {});
    const section = block[sectionId] ?? (block[sectionId] = {});
    section[fieldId] = value;
    return acc;
}
```

As @Nina showed in here answer, you can generalise this to arbitrarily deep assignments.

Comment: hm... it's seems work just like in my case.... I steel get only last fieldId's

Comment: @northernwind oops, fixed

Comment: still gets only last item... Im spend few hours on this, and need rest to test it further

Comment: ups... the first edited sample works, but not second

Comment: @northernwind That's what one gets from fixing in a hurry… I updated only the first snippet bust missed the same fix in the second. Also the third had another typo. Now tested all three of them and fixed the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could take an array of wanted keys for grouping and take either the value or a new object for the next level.

```js
const
    data = [{ blockId: "first-block", sectionId: "first-section", fieldId: "_1", value: "0" }, { blockId: "first-block", sectionId: "first-section", fieldId: "_2", value: "1" }, { blockId: "first-block", sectionId: "second-section", fieldId: "_1", value: "1" }, { blockId: "second-block", sectionId: "first-section", fieldId: "_1", value: "1" }, { blockId: "second-block", sectionId: "some-section", fieldId: "_2", value: "3" }, { blockId: "third-block", sectionId: "other-section", fieldId: "_1", value: "3" }],
    keys = ['blockId', 'sectionId', 'fieldId'],
    result = data.reduce((r, o) => {
        keys.reduce(
            (q, k, i, { length }) => q[o[k]] ??= i + 1 === length ? o.value : {},
            r
        );
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Approach by taking all values of the object and assign the last item as value for the most nested object.

This approach relies on the order of the values in each object.

```js
const
    data = [{ blockId: "first-block", sectionId: "first-section", fieldId: "_1", value: "0" }, { blockId: "first-block", sectionId: "first-section", fieldId: "_2", value: "1" }, { blockId: "first-block", sectionId: "second-section", fieldId: "_1", value: "1" }, { blockId: "second-block", sectionId: "first-section", fieldId: "_1", value: "1" }, { blockId: "second-block", sectionId: "some-section", fieldId: "_2", value: "3" }, { blockId: "third-block", sectionId: "other-section", fieldId: "_1", value: "3" }],
    result = data.reduce((r, o) => {
        const
            values = Object.values(o),
            value = values.pop();
        values.reduce(
            (q, k, i, { length }) => q[k] ??= i + 1 === length ? value : {},
            r
        );
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is very interesting, unfortunately I can't collect 'keys' as array because it's a dynamic and may change in future.

Comment: and how do you know what to group?

Comment: @northernwind If it's dynamic and can change in the future, it's even better to have an array value for it?

Comment: Im simplified my question. Real logic is more complex, and this is not a case for me, unfortunatelly. But I do not say that it wrong.

Comment: What kind of books I need to read to take this in my head?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following,

```js
const flatArray = [
{ "blockId": "first-block", "sectionId": "first-section", "fieldId": "_1", "value": "0" }, 
{ "blockId": "first-block", "sectionId": "first-section", "fieldId": "_2", "value": "1" }, 
{ "blockId": "first-block", "sectionId": "second-section", "fieldId": "_1", "value": "1" }, 
{ "blockId": "second-block", "sectionId": "first-section", "fieldId": "_1", "value": "1" }, 
{ "blockId": "second-block", "sectionId": "some-section", "fieldId": "_2", "value": "3" },
{ "blockId": "third-block", "sectionId": "other-section", "fieldId": "_1", "value": "3" }];


const shapeComplex = (acc, item) => {
    
    if(acc[item.blockId]) {
        acc[item.blockId] = { ...acc[item.blockId], [item.sectionId]: {...acc[item.blockId][item.sectionId], [item.fieldId]: item.value } }
    } else {
        acc[item.blockId] = { ...acc[item.blockId], [item.sectionId]: {[item.fieldId]: item.value } }
    }
    return acc
}

const transformComplex = (arr) => {
    
    return arr.reduce((acc, item) => shapeComplex(acc, item), {});
}

console.log(transformComplex(flatArray));
```

Comment: At this moment this is only one worked code in my case. I don't know who downvote, I'm not seeing nothing wrong with it

Answer (score 0):

You are making a tree from a flat data structure.  Specify the tree hierarchy (levels) and
properties to use to create a leaf node data element.

Example:

```
    function treeFrom (arr, levels, name, value) {
      return arr.reduce( 
        (root,item) => 
        {          
          var node = root;
          for (let level of levels) /* descend to bottom tier */
          {
            levelvalue = item[level];
            if (! node[levelvalue]) node[levelvalue] = {};
            node = node[levelvalue];
          }
          node[item[name]] = item[value];

          return root;
        }
      , 
        {}
      )
    }
    
    console.log ( treeFrom(flatArray, ['blockId', 'sectionId'], 'fieldId', 'value') );
```